# WSO2ESB Create a custom EntitlementCallbackHandler

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, xacml, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I need to create a XACML Policy for a SOAP service based on the method invoked. So I have thought about create a custom callbackhandler in the Entitlement Mediator in wso2esb which passes the operation invoked inside the action parameter to the WSO2IS Entitlement Service. Is it possible to do so? I dont know what else to do. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action property to define your operation
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Entitlement+Mediator